# multi-dimensional array into a single layered array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array being returned

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 616941445
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 1354124203
            )

    )
```

However I want just a single layered array, so i would like something like this.

```
Array
(     
[0] => 616941445
[1] => 1354124203
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
  $arr[$key] = $val['uid'];
}
```

Comment: Or `$arr[$key] = $val['uid']` which is the same…

Comment: i wanted to not have to loop through each result and thought there maybe an array function... I guess not though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$multi_arr = array(
    array(
        'uid' => 616941445
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => 1354124203
    ),
);

$single_arr = array();
foreach($multi_arr as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $val) $single_arr[] = $val;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
    $single_arr[] = $arr[$key]['uid'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As always, when you need to change two level array into one level without preserve keys:

```
$your2DArray = array(/* .. */);
$flatArray = array_map('array_pop', $your2DArray);
```

And like you want to, no loops.

Comment: Actually, there are loops - they are just hidden inside your call to `array_map`.