# PHP Marge 2 Array in single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

all

In my aap, I need to short images based on Tag.
Now in first array there is image tag and in second is url.

1. $results_tag array

   ```
   Array
   (
       [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [meta_value] => Tag 2
       )        
   )
   Array
   (
       [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [meta_value] => Tag 1
       )

       [1] => stdClass Object
       (
           [meta_value] => Tag 3
       )  
   )
   ```
2. $results_url array

   ```
    Array
       (
           [0] => stdClass Object
               (
                   [meta_value] => formidable/madness_beach.jpg
               )

       )
       Array
       (
           [0] => stdClass Object
           (
               [meta_value] => formidable/adfish_beachchair1.jpg
           )

           [1] => stdClass Object
           (
               [meta_value] => formidable/madness_boat1.jpg
           )
   )
   ```

Now, what i actually want is

```
Array
(
[Tag 2] => [formidable/madness_beach.jpg]
[Tag 1] => [formidable/adfish_beachchair1.jpg]
[Tag 3] => [formidable/madness_boat1.jpg]
)
```

So , using this i can short image based on tag.

I have tried

```
$results_tag = array_merge_recursive($results_tag,$results_url);
```

But not getting the output as i want.

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: `$results_tag` seems got 2 array of objects

Comment: yes but both array have same object & value

Comment: *`$results_tag` contains an array. Each element of the array is an array `stdClass` object.* <- Read it carefully. It seems the variable has 1 more nested levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do.

```
$result = array();
$len = count($results_tag);
while($len--) $result[$results_tag[$i]->meta_value] = $results_url[$i]->meta_value;
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume the number of elements is known to be $N.

```
$results = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $N; ++$i ) $results[$results_tag[$i]->meta_value] = $results_url[$i]->meta_value;
```

Comment: Also make sure that no two tags are the same, since you will then lose data.

Comment: Yep! i know that is the issue so i asked this one. I found same solun like yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725954/multi-dimensional-array-into-a-single-layered-array-php

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php 

  $results_tag_one =  array(0 => array('meta_value' => 'Tag 2'));
  $results_tag_two =  array(0 => array('meta_value' => 'Tag 1'),1 => array('meta_value' => 'Tag 3'));
  $results_tag = array_merge($results_tag_one,$results_tag_two);

  $results_url_one =  array(0 => array('meta_value' => 'formidable/madness_beach.jpg'));
  $results_url_two =  array(0 => array('meta_value' => 'formidable/adfish_beachchair1.jpg'),1 => array('meta_value' => 'formidable/madness_boat1.jpg'));
  $results_url = array_merge($results_url_one,$results_url_two);

  $final = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($results_url as $url_data){
    $final[$results_tag[$i]['meta_value']] = $results_url[$i]['meta_value'];
    $i++;
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($final);
  echo "</pre>";
  exit;
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no built-in function which transforms two array of objects into one associative array based on one property.

You could implement something like this assuming you have the correspondence between the array keys:

```
$results = array();
foreach($results_tag as $i => $item)
{
    if(is_array($item){
       foreach($item as $j => $value) {
          $results[$value->meta_value] = $results_url[$i][$j]->meta_value;
       }
    } else {
       $results[$value->meta_value] = $results_url[$i]->meta_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code to handle both cases: elements in the array, or elements in subarrays. Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

```
function flatten($tags, $urls, &$result) {
  if (is_array($tags))
    while (sizeof($tags)>0) {
      $tagschld=array_shift($tags);
      $urlschld=array_shift($urls);
      flatten($tagschld, $urlschld, $result);
    }
  else $result[$tags->meta_value]=$urls->meta_value;
}

$result=array();
flatten($results_tag, $results_url, $result);
print_r($result);
```